# What is the difference between “refer the letter” and “refer to the letter”?

Tags: prepositions, transitivity

I’m asking about usage of “refer” and “refer to”.

Can one say “refer to the letter”?

Is “refer the letter” enough?

Answer (score 3):

*Refer to the letter* basically means to check the letter for information. *Refer the letter* means send or forward the letter to someone.

Comment: One does not usually refer a thing to someone in English. I will send or pass the letter to x. I will refer this matter to x.

Answer (score 2):

Refer can mean that someone is referring to something, usually for information (e.g. refer to a letter, refer to Wikipedia, refer to the manual etc) and it can also mean to send some person to someone else for further investigation. E.g. "I will refer my patient to a heart specialist", or "I'll refer you to an hand-writing expert to analyse the letter". However, I cannot think of a valid usage case for referring an object in this way e.g. "I will refer the letter to a hand-writing expert".

Comment: That's a perfectly good use case. "We will refer your inquiry to our Customer Service Department".  Exactly the same construction, and quite common.

Comment: +1 This is correct: You refer a person to another person. You refer to something or to someone in a text or conversation. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @Lambie Spot on - thanks. I hadn't realised that 'refer to <person or thing>' and 'refer <person> to <person or thing>'

Answer (score 2):

"Refer to the letter" is an instruction asking someone to look to a specific letter *for reference*. You may also hear "*I refer you to the letter*". In this context, refer means "direct the attention of someone to".

"Refer the letter" is not a complete sentence, as it is missing a subject. You might say "refer the letter to your legal team". Here, "refer" means "send or direct someone to".